# Replacing variable/argument value in R

Tags: r

Writing a function, I ran into an error that I realized was coming from a variable retaining its old value after I had assigned a new value to it. The original code that caused the error looked like this. num is an argument to the function

```
if ( num == "best" ) 
   { num <- as.numeric(1) }
```

The error arose later in the code because the value of num had not been changed to 1. When I changed the code to the following, the error went away.

```
if ( num == "best" )
   { rank <- as.numeric(1) }
```

Assigning the new value I wanted to use later in the code to a new variable fixed the problem. What's the deal? I'm pretty sure I've replaced a variable's value before and not had this problem ... is there inconsistent behavior in R in this scenario? Is the fact that num is an argument to the function in which this code exists part of the answer?

Comment: Can you provide a working example?  I used `test <- function(num) {if(num=="best") {num <- as.numeric(1)}; out <- ifelse(num==1,"Yes","No"); return(out)}` and had no problem.

Comment: You likely have something else going on in your code that you're not aware of. Debugging is about **confirming (un)expected behavior**. Provide a reproducible example please.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because if can only evaluate a logical vector of length 1.
I suppose your "num" vector have a length greater than 1 you need to do it by loop. The following will allow you to go through the num vector and do any changes based on your condition.

```
length(num)
  for(i in 1:length(num))
   {
     if ( num[i] =="best")
     {num[i]= 1}
   }
```